# Div containing main controller getting disappeared on button click

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs,
I am having a main div inside which all child divs are present, when I click a button in a child div then my main div gets disappeared, this happens randomly. Sometimes it gets hidden after 2 clicks, sometimes in 4 and sometimes even after 10 clicks.

**HTML Template:**

```
<div ng-cloak ng-app="smart" ng-controller="smartChat" id="chatwindow" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0px;  position: fixed; bottom: 5px; right: 0px; z-index: 10001; background: #FFF; border: 1px solid #898989">
    <div id="cendchat" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" ng-show="EndChatConfirmation" ng-style="endchatconfirmationHeight" style="text-align: center">
       <h4>Are you sure you want to end chat?</h4>
       <button id="yesbutton" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="EndChatOrNot($event);$event.stopPropagation();">Yes</button>
       <button id="nobutton" class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="EndChatOrNot($event);$event.stopPropagation();">No</button>               
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function EndChatOrNot(status) {
    debugger;
    $scope.EndChatConfirmation = false;
    $scope.endchatconfirmationHeight = { height: '0px' };
    if (status.currentTarget.innerHTML.toUpperCase() == 'YES') {
        $scope.ConvHeight = { height: '0px' };
        $scope.FeedBackDiv = true;
        $scope.feedbackHeight = { height: '550px' };
        //  $scope.Islogin=false;
        FunEndChatFromCustomer("", "");
        //$scope.CustomerType = 'Existing';
        //$scope.ExistingOrNew = true;
    }
    else if (status.currentTarget.innerHTML.toUpperCase() == 'NO') {
        $scope.ConvHeight = { height: '435px' };
        // return false;
        //$scope.ExistingOrNew = false;
        //console.log("$scope.Islogin" + $scope.Islogin); 
    }
}
```

Please help me why my main div gets disappeared like this. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Remove `ng-cloak` and try

Comment: i tried that but no luck

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunker code?

Comment: i wish i could make but not possible,sry

Comment: There are some code smell, but I think it's safe to say your problem does not origin from the code you are showing at least.

Comment: i am using <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>

Comment: Why the stopPropagations? Are there elements behind your child divs that are catching the clicks perhaps? Are there nested scopes? Maybe functions with identical names? Seeing the position:fixed, are there any ng-style on the parent div? Since we don't see more than this, it's all just guesses. And with the heavy use of id's, are you sure there are no other say jquery-scripts for example handling those elements. A fixed div without any set height, is 0 if all content is hidden. Maybe add a min-height to make sure that is not the problem.

Comment: Also, with angular we directly touch the DOM as little as possible. Instead of `if (status.currentTarget.innerHTML.toUpperCase() == 'YES')` I would pass in one more variable `function EndChatOrNot(confirm) {` and call it with ng-click="EndChatOrNot(true);" If we are lucky we don't even need the $event, but as I said, I think those `stopPropagation()` are fishy. But just to check you could go all the way and try with `$event.stopImmediatePropagation();` if you are having trouble with some other event-handler getting triggered.

Comment: tried using $event.stopImmediatePropagation(); but still same problem